# Edit script actions directly in Performance Center / ALM 12

Tags: vugen, hp-alm, hp-performance-center

I am using:

- Application Lifecycle Management Version 12.50
- HP Performance Center 12.50

from Internet Explorer.

Under **Test Plan** I try to **edit** the **Actions** of a Script.

I checked out the script, I can rename it, but I don't see a way to edit its actions under the **Test Script** tab.

I always open it in an additional tool (HP Virtual User Generator), but this is a slow process.

Is it possible to edit the script actions directly from ALM / PC?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are no functions that allow you to edit tests in the Performance Center.